# 2 Applications in the same project

Tags: ios, xcode-project

I created 2 ios projects, but now I want to erase them in the appstore and create an unique project with a simple button which display 2 buttons
Button A go to application A
Button B go to application B

I imported the project A in my new project (just projectA.xcodeproj) but when I link the button I get this error message :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard
>   named 'MainIphone' ...

What is the way to import and link 2 project in one ?

Comment: Should I use many targets and not many projects?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have not included all the files from project A in your new combined project.  Make sure when you select the storyboard in the Project Navigator on the left pane, and the File Inspector in the right pan in Xcode that the checkmark for the Target you are building is selected in the "Target Membership" section.

Comment: The Target selected is the Project A.
Should it be for the new project ?

Comment: It should be whichever target you are running when you run the project in XCode.  If you are building a new, single application, you need a single target for the new AB application.  If I understand your question, you now have a new project that wish to create a single application from.  That new application should have a new target that includes all the files from App A and App B (you may have some naming conflicts and need to re-name some files that overlap between App A and App B.